# Most women hate me, some even scream at me!

Tags: riddle

> I'm always horny but so lonely.
>   Most women hate me, some even scream at me!
>   I might be puny,
>   but don't mock me! I don't have to take this crap! Although I sometimes do.
>   When a few of us get together we are quite popular!
>   Most prefer with fruits, but others prefer my beverage.

Who am I?

Comment: Maybe Cows o.o?

Comment: Cows are highly known for being puny.  And for being hated by women. ;)

Comment: cows beverage ? O_O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you ...

> a beetle?

I'm always horny but so lonely.

> many beetles have prominent horns, and generally live alone

Most women hate me, some even scream at me!

> Women stereotypically hate bugs

I might be puny,

> Beetles are small

but don't mock me! I don't have to take this crap! Although I sometimes do.

> Dung beetles take crap all the time.

When a few of us get together we are quite popular!

> The Beatles were immensely popular!

Most prefer with fruits, but others prefer my beverage.

> Beetlejuice is a wonderful film.

Comment: Well @Rubio strikes again. Good job on solving my riddle so fast.

Comment: about the crap, there is the [Dung beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dung_beetle)

Comment: Indeed. That's why my answer says "Dung beetles take crap all the time."

Answer (score 0):

Are you a

> cockroach

Explanation Follows

I'm always horny but so lonely.

> Horn may be the reference to its antennae and studies proved cockroaches feel loneliness ([Link](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/80beats/2012/05/03/cockroaches-get-lonely-kind-of-but-a-little-feather-poking-can-help/#.WCv2oeZ97IU))

Most women hate me, some even scream at me!

> Women hate cockroaches and even scream when they see one.

I might be puny,

> Cockroaches are puny.

but don't mock me! I don't have to take this crap! Although I sometimes do.

> Cockroaches live in waste, junk and craps.

When a few of us get together we are quite popular!

> Might be a reference to 'Oggy and the cockroaches' cartoon series.

Most prefer with fruits, but others prefer my beverage.

> Might be a reference to Coke